# Elements positioned relative gets dis aligned when screen resolution changes or new element is added to UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create layout similar to the figure shown below,
[image]

But when I design I see only this,
[image]
To position the elements marked in red, I use position: relative property but its position is altered when screen is changed or new element is added.

I aspire to be professional UI designer, to make website responsive I did come across flexbox and media queries. How do I use them here? 
I use div and table as primary elements to structure the layout. Is this what professional UI designers do?

This is the layout I am trying to design,I imagine each section as div and wherever I find rows and columns I see them as table. Am I going in right direction?

Here is the code snippet

```css
#versionDiv {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 45px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
  
}
.space{
    height:10px;
}

table{
    position: relative;
    left:50px;
}

#borroweddiv {
    background-color: #ffc594;
    min-height:250px;
}


#borrowedtable tr td input {
    background-color: #ffc594;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#borrowedtable td button {
    position: relative;
    left:100px;  
}

#dateColumn {
 position: relative;
 left:50px;    
}

button{
    height:44px;
    width:178px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 1px;
    background-color:#f2a900;
    font-family: ffunit;
    font-weight : 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom : 5px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#ReturnAll{
    position: relative;
    bottom:20px;
    left:100px;
}


h3,select{
    display: inline-block;
}

input {
    
    height:45px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width:380px;
}

input[type=date] {
    position: relative;
    width:180px;
    left: 50px;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
}

#borrowablediv {
    background-color: papayawhip;
    min-height: 250px;
}

select,option {
 
    display: unset !important;
    text-indent :5px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:250px;
}

#borrowButtons {
    position: fixed;
    left:1000px;
    bottom:500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="  ./jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.structure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" />  
<script src="./jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />  
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="versionDiv">
    &ensp;&ensp; <h3>Version</h3>&ensp;
    <select>
      <option value="1">text1</option>
      <option value="1">text2</option>
      <option value="1">text3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div id="borroweddiv">
    &ensp;&ensp; <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Feature</h3>&ensp;
    <table id="borrowedtable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Feature</th>
          <th id="dateColumn">Date</th>
          <th><button id="ReturnAll">Return All</button></th>
        </tr>
        
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="date"></td>
          <td><button>Return Now</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="date"></td>
          <td><button>Return Now</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="date"></td>
          <td><button>Return Now</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="date"></td>
          <td><button>Return Now</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>

  <div id="borrowablediv">
    &ensp;&ensp; <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Feature</h3>&ensp;
    <table id="borrowabletable">
      <tr>
        <thead>
          <th>Feature</th>
        </thead>
      </tr>  
  
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option value="1">text1</option>
              <option value="1">text2</option>
              <option value="1">text3</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>  
      </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
  <div id="borrowButtons">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Return Date</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="date"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>Borrow</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you think table, think flexbox or css grid. Tables are just a headache you don't want to deal with and they're not responsive by nature so you have to babysit them on each screen size or breakpoint if you use media queries. Flexbox is fairly simple to learn there's plenty of tutorials online you can start with.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)